# Estimating Time to failure when there is no failure pattern

Tags: regression, machine-learning, predictive-models

Assume I have data from some sensors and the goal is to estimate the failure time, however, some sensors never fail, and the question is what label to assign to those sensors. For example, consider: Assume sensor 1 fails after 512 seconds, sensor 2 fails after 125s but sensor n never fails, then what value should we assign to this?

If I do not include anything for this sensor then for this testing, I can not predict if this sensor never fails. If I include 0, it will not be correct since it means it is already failed. However, I am not sure if I assign a large value, this would be the right approach. I would appreciate it if anyone can suggest a solution for this.

Comment: Look up survival models.